# Cannot create site from template due to missing column

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, site-template

I have created a site template that contains a list with a calculated column. Here is the column formula:

```
="<DIV><img src='"&IF([Project Status]="On track","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF",IF([Project Status ="Warning","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF","/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF"))&"'></DIV>"
```

All it does is check the value of a choice field and returns an image that can be displayed in the list:[image: Project State]

I am able to save this site as a template with the list and calculated column just fine. However, when I try to create a new site from the template I receive an error stating the formula is referencing a column that does not exist and no site is created.

Things I have tried:

1. Saving the site template without content
2. Deleting the list and recreating it from a list template
3. Deleting the calculated column and recreating it at the parent site level

Does anyone have an idea what would cause this? Or are there any alternatives? I would prefer to keep the icon in the list instead of creating a separate status list.

The columns are inherited from a custom parent site content type and I am using SP 2010 with Publishing enabled.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You may be lacking a closed bracket.. IF([Project Status ="Warning","/

Comment: Are you restoring the site in same farm? Also does the site collection where you are restoring also contain the inherited content type?

Comment: Yes on both questions, I think. We requested the site from our SP enterprise admin so I am working within a particular site collection. In fact, I'm not even the site collection admin, just an owner.